# word compression function using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

Can someone tell me why it seems I am not getting the right results using this regular expression in this python code? I would have thought, for example, that the initial vowel in the word "about" should not disappear. Thanks.

```
>>> sentence = "But the third reason Americans should care about Europe is more important    even than the risk of a renewed financial crisis."
>>> regexp = r'^[AEIOUaeiou]+|[AEIOUaeiou]+$|[^AEIOUaeiou]'
>>> def compress(word):
...     pieces = re.findall(regexp, word)
...     return ''.join(pieces)
>>> compress(sentence)
'Bt th thrd rsn mrcns shld cr bt rp s mr mprtnt vn thn th rsk f  rnwd fnncl crss.'
```

Comment: Can you give us a little context as to what you want your regular expressions to do and what the problem you're trying to solve is? Right now the third bit of your regular expression would match everything that's not a vowel.

Comment: I was trying to compress words by omitting word-internal vowels and just retaining consonants and initial/final vowels. That is the regexp assignment above. The compress function finds the pieces and joins them back together again. Is that a little clearer?

Comment: You could also do that with: `re.sub(r'(?i)\B[aeiou]\B', '', word)`

Comment: Thanks, @Qtax. That does work. Can you explain why it works for the article "a"? It seems that the article "a" which has a boundary on each side should vanish? And why is (?i) necessary? I get the same results when I omit it. Thanks.

Comment: @nlper, the regex only removes the vowels which have not-word-boundary (`\B`) on both sides, ie. the vowels that are completely in inside a word. "a" is not removed because it does not have not-word-boundaries around it. `(?i)` makes the regex case insensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

^ and $ anchor to the ends of the entire string, so you're not anchoring to the beginning and end of each word, but to the beginning and end of the entire sentence. When the sentence is only the word "about," it works as you expect. I think you want to anchor to word boundaries (\b) instead.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

This might do what you want it to:

```
regexp = r'\b[AEIOUaeiou]+|[AEIOUaeiou]+\b|[^AEIOUaeiou]'
```

Comment: +1 This was a nice answer complete with a link to docs and working code.  Welcome to SO :-)

Comment: A '+' sign  must be added to the part '[^AEIOUaeiou]'. Without '+', the list **pieces** has value ``['B', 't', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'd', ' ', 'r', 's', 'n', ' ', 'A', 'm', 'r', 'c', 'n', 's', ' ', 's', 'h', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'e', ' ',.....`` . With sign '+' , it is ``['B', 't th', 'e', ' th', 'rd r', 's', 'n ', 'A', 'm', 'r', 'c', 'ns sh', 'ld c', 'r', 'e', ' ',......``

Comment: Thanks @Gary Fixler. That did the trick. I had an inkling that the whole sentence was being treated as the string but didn't know how to remedy it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`'^[AEIOUaeiou]+'` allows to match only a succession of vowels being at the start of a string

`'[AEIOUaeiou]+$'` allows to match only a succession of vowels being at the end of a string

`'[^AEIOUaeiou]'` allows to match only a character not being a vowel

If it was `'[^AEIOUaeiou]+'` , it would allow to match any succession of non-vowel character

Presently with your regex's pattern, you catch only non-vowel character one at once in the used sentence.

Your comment explains what you want to do.
There's no need ti use regex to do that; I think the problem is even harder, or at least more complicated, to solve with regexes

Does this fulfills your need ? :

```
def compress(word):
    if len(word)<3:
        yield word
    else:
        yield word[0]
        for c in word[1:-1]:
            if c not in 'AEIOUaeiou':
                yield c
        yield word[-1]


print ' '.join(''.join(compress(word)) for word in sentence.split())
```

Comment: Thanks, @eyquem. Your code works produces the same results. I am trying to use regular expressions because they are so compact and powerful.